# SQL Agent Job is not stopping, which have SSIS package who have Snowflake connection

Tags: sql, ssis, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-agent-job

we are retrieving data from snowflake to SQL database using SQL Agent Jobs.

We have created a SSIS Package for fetching data from snowflake and inserting it to SQL Database using the ODBC driver connectivity.

When i run the SSIS package it's working fine , but when i run it in SQL Agent jobs , job is not stopping even after execution and it is not coming out of that particular step.

I have tested the job by using some other Package which doesn't have Snowflake connection and it was working fine.

So, can you please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is "Run as" for that step , does that use has enough permission  (probably to snowflake ) ?

Comment: But if its permission issue then it shouldn't fetch the data from snowflake right?
Its fetching and data from Snowflake and inserting to our SQL Db .